# Не могу вычислить производную в Python

Tags: python, sympy

Пытаюсь вычислить производную функции f(x,y)=e^(x+y)*(x^2-2y^2). Возникает ошибка: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf2 in position 143: invalid continuation byte. С производными полегче (напр., 2x + 3y) все работает.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
import math
from sympy import Float


x=1.5
y=0.5
h=0.4
fxy=0
fX=0
fy=0
gradf=0
delta=0
# таблица
# x y f(x,y) f'x f'y |gradf| delta. Начальные x y уже есть

#1. Подставляем x y в функцию  
fxy=(math.exp(x+y))*(x**2-((2*y)**2))
print(fxy)

#2. Находим производную от функции по иксу

x, y=symbols('x y')
diff((exp**(x+y))*(x**2-((2*y)**2)),x)


#3. Находим производную от функции по игреку


#4. находим |gradf|=sqrt((f'(x))^2+(f'(y))^2))
#5. x(i+1)=x(i)-h*f'(x), y(i+1)=y(i)-h*f'(y)
#6. Считаем точность: |gradf(i)-gradf(i+1)|<delta
##Коррекция шага:
#Если f(x,y(i))<f(x,y(i-1)), то h=h(i-1)/2

#f(x,y)=e^(x+y)*(x^2-2y^2)
```

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20UnicodeDecodeError&searchOn=3). ну а вообще надо просто удалить этот мусорный символ, стоящий на 143 позиции в вашем файле. p.s. вы нам привели только 70 байт из этого файла, так что смотрите на него сами.

Comment: Весь код:
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
import math
from sympy import Float


x=1.5
y=0.5
h=0.4
fxy=0
fX=0
fy=0
gradf=0
delta=0
# таблица
# x y f(x,y) f'x f'y |gradf| delta. Начальные x y уже есть

#1. Подставляем x y в функцию
fxy=(math.exp(x+y))*(x**2-((2*y)**2))
print(fxy)

#2. Находим производную от функции по иксу

x, y=symbols('x y')
diff((exp**(x+y))*(x**2-((2*y)**2)),x)

Comment: код нужно добавить в вопрос, а не в комментарий

Comment: Добавил. Первый раз пользуюсь сервисом, туплю

Comment: ну, если это весь файл, и если в нём используется не двух-четырёх-байтная кодировка, то 143 байт приходится где-то в район первой-второй строки с комментариями. удалите эти строки и проверьте воспроизводимость ошибки.

Comment: Если файл сохранить в cp1251, то python3.10 выдаст ошибку "SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xf2' in file ... on line 16, but no encoding declared; see https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details", что соответствует описанной вами проблеме. Пересохраните файл в кодировке utf-8. Ну и кстати байт \xf2 в кодировке cp1251 - это буква т (`b"\xf2".decode("cp1251")` возвращает `'т'`), соответственно ругается на код начиная с комментария "# таблица"

Comment: Дело в том, что если я просто меняю функцию, оставляя комментарии и все что было до строки с diff, то все работает

Comment: Ну значит вы при оставлении комментариев каким-то образом пересохранили код в utf-8. Вот нужно сделать то же самое, только без удаления всего остального. Проблема именно в кодировке кода.

Comment: Подскажите, как с помощью Studio найти символ, на который указывает ошибка? (position 143)

Comment: Берете, пишете код: `with open("имя_файла.py", "rb") as file: print(file.read()[:143])` - выведет часть текста до 143 байта.